# CumSum column only if previous ids are between 2 values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have the below:

Dataframe:

```
id    endId   startId   ownerId   value
1     50          50          10        105 
2     51          50          10        240
3     52          50          10        420
4     53          53          10        470
5     40          40          11        320
6     41          40          11        18
7     55          55          12        50
8     57          55          12        412
9     59          55          12        398
10    60          57          12        320
```

What I would like to do is to sum all the "value" columns where the endId is between the current startId and the current endId for the same ownerId.

Output should be:

```
id    endId   startId   ownerId   value    output
1     50          50          10        105      105     # Nothing between 50 and 50
2     51          50          10        240      345     # Found 1 record (endId with id 1)
3     52          50          10        420      765     # Found 2 records (endId with id 1 and 2)
4     53          53          10        470      470     # Nothing else between 53 and 53
5     40          40          11        320      320     # Reset because Owner is different
6     41          40          11        18       338     # Found 1 record (endId with id 5)
7     55          55          12        50       50      # ...
8     57          55          12        412      462
9     59          55          12        398      860
10    60          57          12        320      1130    # Found 3 records between 57 and 60 (endId with id 8, 9 and 10)
```

I tried to use diff, groupby.cumsum, etc. but I cannot get what I need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use numpy broadcasting to identify the rows that you are looking for:

```
# Create new df with ownerId as index
df2=df.set_index('ownerId')
df2['output']=0

# Loop over the various ownerIds
for k in df2.index:
    refend=df2.loc[k,'endId'].values
    refstart=df2.loc[k,'startId'].values

    # Identify values matching the condition
    i,j=np.where((refend[:,None]<=refend)&(refend[:,None]>=refstart))
    # Groupby and sum
    dfres=pd.concat([df2.loc[k].iloc[j].endId.reset_index(drop=True),
                     df2.loc[k].iloc[i].value.reset_index(drop=True)],
                    axis=1).groupby('endId').sum()
    df2.loc[k,'output']=dfres.value.values

# reset index
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

the output is:

```
   ownerId  id  endId  startId  value  output
0       10   1     50       50    105     105
1       10   2     51       50    240     345
2       10   3     52       50    420     765
3       10   4     53       53    470     470
4       11   5     40       40    320     320
5       11   6     41       40     18     338
6       12   7     55       55     50      50
7       12   8     57       55    412     462
8       12   9     59       55    398     860
9       12  10     60       57    320    1130
```

**Edit**

You can avoid the avoid the **for-loop** with the following:

```
refend=df.loc[:,'endId'].values
refstart=df.loc[:,'startId'].values

i,j=np.where((refend[:,None]<=refend)&(refend[:,None]>=refstart))

dfres=pd.concat([df.iloc[j].endId.reset_index(drop=True),
                     df.loc[:,['ownerId','value']].iloc[i].reset_index(drop=True)],
                    axis=1).groupby(['ownerId','endId']).sum()

df['output']=dfres.value.values
```

Comment: Hmm it seems I am getting an exception with line: df2.loc. ValueError('Must have equal len keys and value ' ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable

Comment: Would you be able to explain what is this line doing as it is raising the above exception?

Comment: That line simply copies the results to df2, can you isolate the values that give you the problem? I'm guessing this should happen only for a certain index value so you can just print `df2.loc[k]` after the error.

Comment: Yes indeed. I identified the index which is wrong. this is because I had a nan in my data set. The solution you gave me seems to be working fine ! I am currently checking before marking it as resolved

Comment: cool, let me know if you have any other question! As a general comment It would be nice to avoid the for loop but I didn't find a simple way around it...

Comment: I have been trying for 2 3 hours and I am still learning with panda. So I tried as much as possible. Something I added in your answer is to store in a variable the current ownerid at the beginning, and if that's the same as the previous, I have a "continue". I thus loop only if the ownerId is "new"

Comment: I found a nice way to avoid the for-loop, it was easier than expected! Give it a try and let me know if it works...

Comment: Using your 2nd answer, It seems that the dfres is an empty dataframe using my data set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202214/discussion-between-baccandr-and-williamw).

Answer (score 1):

I made a copy of df to df2, to keep the original data.
I suggest you to break the task in two steps:

```
#change everything
df2['output'] =  df.groupby('ownerId')['value'].cumsum()


#check and update if it applies
df2['output'] = np.where((df2['endId']<= df['startId']),                          
                           df2['value'],     #copy value from
                           df2['output'])    #place value into 

print(df2)
id  endId  startId  ownerId  value  output
0   1     50       50       10    105     105
1   2     51       50       10    240     345
2   3     52       50       10    420     765
3   4     53       53       10    470     470
4   5     40       40       11    320     320
5   6     41       40       11     18     338
6   7     55       55       12     50      50
7   8     57       55       12    412     462
8   9     59       55       12    398     860
9  10     60       57       12    320    1180
```

Print of the logic:

[image]

I am sorry people, but I still don't get it.
For ownerId 10 and 11 the record where endId and startId are sharing the same value is being counted on the accumulative sum.
And it seems to be ok. But for some reason you are saying that the same rule doesn't apply to ownerId 12.
I understand that id from 7 to 10 should be considered. The pattern seems to be to not count the values when endId and startId
matches on the highest value, it happens on id 4.

Comment: Yes as mentioned by Henry, unfortunately, this does not work for me

Comment: @HenryYik  I think the user who asked the question forgot to sum the id 7, which adds 50 to the accumulative sum.
 It belongs to same ownerId 12.I understand it is the same logic applied to id 0,1,2 ownerId 10

Comment: Yes I confirm, Id 7 should not be in the cumsum. Because its startid= 55 and its endId=55 whereas the current startId= 57. I need to include only if other_startId <= current_startId <= other_endId

Comment: @WilliamW I added an explanation with a print within my answer.

Comment: Hello @powerPixie. What you need to compare is for the same owner: the current startId with the startId and endId of the previous records. If this startid is between the previous startId and endId, you can cumsum it. If there is no previous records with previous_startId <= startId <= previous_endId, the output should for the current record should be the same as the current value

Comment: With my above example, for the last record, the current_startid is 57. the ids 8,9, 10 has a start_id <= current_startId <= end_startId. The record with id 7 has startId = endId = 55. Does it make sense ?